# How To Use Nagios perl Scripts in My Java Code?

Tags: java, perl, jsp, nagios

I want to use a Nagios perl script such as "check_http". I want to get the status information from it using:

```
check_http -w 5 -c 10 -I 192.168.1.105
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you do, what you want to do is write your own checkHTTP class with an isUp() method that you call rather than having a dependency on a Perl script written for a specialised embedded interpreter.

By all means read through the text of the Perl script to get an idea of the structure required, but a Java project shouldn't depend on a Perl script (until the integration team get their hands on it and have to get it to talk to some piece of middle-ware ;) )

There shouldn't be much more than a couple of import statements in this code anyway.